# How to render YUV420P frames using DirectX?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, render, directx-11, texture2d

I'm using FFMPEG C++ to decode a video file.

I decoded the frames under YUV420P format in System Memory.

Next step, I want to render these frames by using DirectX.

I searched many times, and I know that I have to use the texture2D, but there is not any code sample for my case.

How to create a texture2D from YUV420 (or RGB instead) from System Memory and render it to the screen.

And the performance is also important, so I need the best way to do it. 
Someone can show me the sample code?

Many Thanks!

Comment: You could use libswscale (included in the FFmpeg project) to convert from yuv420p to rgb, and then render the RGB frame with DirectX. Alternatively, you could create 3 textures (one for each y, u, and v plane), pass them to a shader (that you'd have to write), and do the conversion in the shader to RGB. [Here's the shader mpv uses to convert from yuv420p to RGB](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/blob/master/video/out/d3d_shader_yuv.hlsl).

Comment: Thank you!
I can convert to RGB, But I need the sample code to create texture2D from RGB data, and render it.

Comment: Are you solve it? I want upload YUV420 to texture, and use shader for get RBGA,... . (not use mediate)